# Submit Login Form Using AJAX and get response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am trying to build a front end HTML page that takes in a username and password and then uses a javascript function to show response depending on the answer received from the server. I am a super noob when it comes to web development so can anyone help me correct my code ?
Thank you

This is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#login").click(function(){
                    username=$("#user_name").val();
                    password=$("#password").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type    : "POST",
                        url     : "login.php",
                        data    : "username="+username+"&password="+password,
                        success : function(html){
                            if(html=='true'){
                                $("#add_err").html("right username And password");
                                //$("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
                                //$("#shadow").fadeOut();
                                //$("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' class='red' id='logout'>Logout</a>");    
                            }else{
                                $("#add_err").html("Wrong username And password");
                            }
                        },
                        beforeSend:function(){
                            $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
        <div id="profile">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){ ?>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </body>

    <?php if(empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){ ?>
    <div class="container" id="login_form">
        <section id="content">
            <form action="login.php">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="user_name"  name="user_name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password"  name="password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="login"  />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="button"> </div> 
        </section>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</html>
```

And this is my login.php code which uses `curl` to forward username/pass to appropriate url

```
<?php

session_start();
$url =  http://    //url that recieves username/password and responds if credentials are correct after contacting database
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;

?>
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Is there an error displayed? I'm not sure where to start looking, give us a bit more info.

Comment: Well it just says loading, but I want to make sure if the code is written correctly, like if the javascript is written right  and if it interacts correctly with login.php

Answer (score 1):

javascript

```
$("#login").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'login.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#Form').serialize(),
    success: function (x) {                
      $("#add_err").html(x.response);
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
      $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

html form

```
   <form id="Form" action="login.php">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="user_name"  name="user_name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password"  name="password"/>
        </div>
            <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
        <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="login"  />
        </div>
    </form>
```

php

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url =  http://    //url that recieves username/password and responds if     credentials are correct after contacting database
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output=array(); 
$output['response']=$result;    
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: This displays an blank page. Am i missing something

Comment: at what point do you see a blank page? you changed the $url on php to an actual value right?

Comment: Ok no blank page now but i seem to getting this response:

{"response":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-\/\/IETF\/\/DTD HTML 2.0\/\/EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>301 Moved Permanently<\/title>\n<\/head><body>\n<h1>Moved Permanently<\/h1>\n<p>The document has moved <a href=\"https:\/\/the http address i am sending POST request to\">here<\/a>.<\/p>\n<\/body><\/html>\n"}

Comment: Hard for me to guess. Are you sure the URL is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first things first: you can use `action="form.php"` OR the click handler `$("#login").click(function(){});`. Using both is redundant and will make your javascript form checker void.

So go ahead and remove `action="login.php"`.

Next step is making sure your `login.php` script is receiving everything correctly. For debug purposes, add

```php
var_dump($_POST);
exit();
```

To the top of `login.php`, then add

```js
console.debug(html);
```

To the top of your ajax `success` function. That'll show you in the console what the PHP script is seeing for `$_POST` variables.

Hopefully that helps you get started on diagnosing whatever issue is going on.